# Complex object inside another one

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have the following class

```
class A {
private:
   B b;
public:
   A();
}

class B {
public:
   void foo();
   void bar();
   void foz();
   ........
}
```

B has a lot of methods. Sometimes is needed for a "customer" of class A to use method of class B. I could return a reference of B, but in this case I should return a const reference because returning a non-const reference of a private object is not good programming. If the reference is const, foo, bar and so on can't be called because they aren't const. So the only "clean" way seems to recreate the same interfaces in A using delegation to B. But this approach is not really good because I should recreate all the interfaces in A. As alternative I could set B as public in A, but it seems "strange" to me. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Why not use inheritage?

Comment: Returning non-constant references is not "bad programming". See e.g. `std::vector` and it's element-access operators. You can always make *two* "getter" functions to get the `B` object, one marked `const` which returns a `const` reference, and the other which returns a non-const reference. The compiler will then choose the correct one to use automatically.

Comment: What might be bad is using "getters" breaks some of the encapsulation. But if it's really "bad" or not depends on your design and use-cases.

Comment: element access operator provides non-const reference because you can change value of vector based on that

Comment: If you are calling B functions directly then why create A object use B object directly.Otherwise if customer of A class wants to call B functions through A object then there is some flaw in design

Comment: I sense that OP doesn't know about component-entity system, but tries to invent something similar

Comment: Although it isn't necessarily bad practice, I'd need a fairly strong justification before simply returning a reference to a private member.   Why not simply have a getter and setter for the `B`?   That way, the caller can obtain a copy of the internal `B` from the `A`, change it as needed, and then pass back the new one.   And the setter can check the supplied `B` in order to avoid getting bad state.

Comment: @Peter It could, but the B object here is not copiable only movable because it contains a std::mutex

Comment: @greywolf82 That suggests the caller should be prevented from accessing it at all.  Which means your class `A` needs to provide needed operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is mainly an encapsulation question, and what you want to *advertise* in the public interface of class A.

If class B is also a *public* class - read can normally be used by users of class A and not a class internal to a library or framework - and if you want the existence of a B subobject to exist in the public documentation of class A and if you want to allow any operation on the B object, you can safely provide a getter.

If any of the above conditions is false, then the getter would break encapsulation and you would better define delegating methods in class A.

Depending on the general design, it could make sense to declare an *interface* class (say C) with only the methods that you want to allow from class A, and have B a subclass from C. Then you could safely declare a getter returning a reference on a C object:

```
class C {
public:
   void foo();  // optionally virtual or pure virtual...
   void bar();
   void foz();
};

class B: public C {
....    // other members not relevant for what is public for A users
};

class A {
private:
   B b;
public:
   A();
   C& getB() {
       return b;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. You create a `getb()` and return reference to B. Its not bad programming in you case particularly.
Solution 2. Create interface function for each corresponding function of b and call them.

```
void A::foo()
{
    b.foo();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make the data member `protected`instead of `private`. Documentation says that *protected members are not as private as `private` members, which are accessible only to members of the class in which they are declared, but they are not as public as `public` members, which are accessible in any function*. `protected`members (be they data members of method members) serve the role you're looking for : they are not accessible from everywhere (safe coding practices), but you can still manage them in *clean* ways when it makes sense :

1. If class A has an attribute of type B, is has access to B's
   `protected` and `public`members
2. `friend`functions can access both `protected` and `public`members of a class they are `friend` with.
3. When preceding the name of a base class, the `protected` keyword specifies that the public and protected members of the base class are protected members of its derived classes.

Here, you're interested by the first item of the list : you can access B' methods from A; BUT B has still safeguards.

When I run the following code (adapted from your code) :

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class B {
public:
    void foo() { cout << "foo" << endl; };
    void bar() { cout << "bar" << endl; };
    void foz() { cout << "foz" << endl; };
};

class A {
protected: // <===== THIS IS THE SIGNIFICANT BIT
    B b; 
public:
    A() {
        b.foo();
        b.bar();
        b.foz();
        cout << "A constructor" << endl;
    };
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A myA;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following console output :

```
foo
bar
foz
A constructor
```

Which shows that I can access B's methods from A.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question